# Can I safely remove mariadb from Centos Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, mariadb

I just did a clean install of CentOS Linux.  The first thing I did after installing CentOS was to download MySQL and try to install the `-server` `rpm` file.  But the installation fails with a lot of messages stating conflicts with MariaDB packages which seem to be redundant to those in MySQL.  I want to use MySQL as my database.

Are there any reasons why I should not just delete `mariadb`, so that the conflicts can be resolved? If `mariadb` performs some important functions in CentOS, I do not want to end up having my system crash.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use MariaDB instead?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have never even heard of MariaDB.  This is a development machine for an app that was developed with MySQL.

Comment: https://mariadb.org/

Comment: MariaDB provides all the functions offered by MySQL. It's created by many of MySQL's original developers (before the Sun Micro - Oracle saga). It would be wise to consider keeping it; it's pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use MariaDB as mysql version 5.5 for it is just another MYSQL branch...

In Centos 7, it is a alternative project of oracle mysql. It contains all mysql functions and optimize structures, data processing, Algorithm etc..

you could even login the server with a "mysql" command.

you don't need to pay attentions on the name, it is no problem to your former mysql projects.

ps:
I don't think that a linux system will have a "clean", "pure" os environment. Linux is a free and open source system which means you could install and remove every thing with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

To have MySQL database functionality you can install either the MySQL packages or the MariaDB packages. MariaDB is a fork originating from the same MySQL code base. For compatibility see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

Yes, you can remove MariaDB packages and replace them by MySQL packages.